# How to draw Jacobi/chord diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]I want to draw the Jacobi/chord diagrams(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.10425.pdf) in tikz but I have no idea how to draw them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest you start with some basic tutorials, such as those at the start of the PGF manual. You really just need `\path circle ...` or `\node [circle] ...` to begin, together with some curved lines. If you get stuck, post the code you've got and ask a specific question. (You may get lucky and somebody's bored, but do-it-all-for-me questions are less likely to get enthusiastic responses.)

Comment: For both diagrams, the `knots` library will be helpful to interrupt the curves at their intersections. For the left, there's even a `braids` library by the same author. Though, in these simple cases, you could get away with a `double` path that draws a white curve over the others before it draws the colored one with a thinker line width.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2):

The source code of the article is available on arXiv https://arxiv.org/format/1912.10425 and it uses TikZ to draw the digrams. This means you don't need to know how to draw such diagrams because you can simply look up how the diagrams are created.

For example the one at the top right:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{orangeii}{RGB}{240,90, 10}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.05,0.25,0.65}

\begin{document}

    
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{scope}

  \clip (0,0) circle (2);

  \draw[draw=orangeii, fill=orangeii] (90+120-30:2) circle (.07);
  \draw[draw=orangeii, fill=orangeii] (90+360-30:2) circle (.07);
  \draw[thick, orangeii] (90+120-30:2) to[bend right=19] (90+360-30:2);

  \draw[draw=orangeii, fill=orangeii] (90+240-60:2) circle (.07);
  \draw[draw=orangeii, fill=orangeii] (90+360-60:2) circle (.07);
  \draw[thick, orangeii] (90+240-60:2) to[bend left=19] (90+360-60:2);

  \draw[draw=white, fill=white] (90+60:.79) circle (.07);

  \draw[draw=orangeii, fill=orangeii] (90+120-90:2) circle (.07);
  \draw[draw=orangeii, fill=orangeii] (90+240-90:2) circle (.07);
  \draw[thick, orangeii] (90+120-90:2) to[bend left=19] (90+240-90:2);

  \end{scope}

  \draw[darkblue, ultra thick] (0+2+90:2) arc (0+90+2:90+120-2:2);
  \draw[darkblue, ultra thick] (90+120+2:2) arc (90+120+2:90+240-2:2);
  \draw[darkblue, ultra thick] (90+240+2:2) arc (90+240+2:90+360-2:2);

  \draw (90+120-10:2.25) node {\tiny $1$};
  \draw (90+240-10:2.25) node {\tiny $2$};
  \draw (90+360-10:2.25) node {\tiny $3$};

  \draw[->] (90+90-10+212:2.3) arc (90+90-10+212:90+110-10+212:2.3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 That's very clever : )

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. First `clip` the outer circle, then draw chords from back to front, using `double` style to give the effect of passing over previously drawn chords. Use polar coordinates `(θ:r)` for endpoints. Use `bend left=<angle>` or `bend right=<angle>` for chords. You can also use `to[out=<angle>, in=<angle>]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\colorlet{chordcolor}{orange}
\colorlet{arccolor}{blue}

\tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle, fill=chordcolor, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt},
    chord/.style={
        white, line width=1pt, double=orange, double distance=.6pt, 
        decoration={markings, mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .999 with 
        {\node[dot]{};}},
        postaction=decorate
    },
    Jacobi/.style={line width=2pt, arccolor}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

% clip outer circle to prevent drawing of full dots on circle 
\clip (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];

% draw two chords and name coordinates for edges 
\draw[chord](150:1) to[bend left]coordinate[pos=.4](A) (260:1);
\draw[chord](170:1) to[bend right=15]coordinate[pos=.4](B) (60:1);

% draw edge
\draw[chord] (A) to[bend right=10] (B);

% draw chord and name coordinate 
\draw[chord](290:1) to[bend left=60]coordinate[pos=.4](C) (320:1);

% make a path to locate position of internal vertex, then draw internal chord
\path(10:1) to[bend left=15]coordinate[pos=.2](D) (130:1);
\draw[chord, looseness=1.5] (C) to[out=120, in=120] (D);

% draw chord "on top" with dot at appropriate position
\draw[chord](10:1) to[bend left=15]node[dot, pos=.2]{} (130:1);

% draw chord
\draw[chord](235:1) to[bend left=15] (-5:1);

% draw circle
\draw[Jacobi] (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```